# What should be path of learning a ReactJS(facebook) for AngularJs developer?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm AngularJS(1.5,2 and 4) developer. Now, I want to learn ReactJS from scratch.

> Can anyone help me what should be learning curve for me to start
>   ReactJS?

I'm lfeeling very difficult to learn it while comparing with AngularJS 2?

What are the main things I should be focused in ReactJS?

Comment: Stop comparing them....they are completely different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was an AngularJS and Angular 2 developer before becoming ReactJS developer. To be honest, I didn't feel it's very difficult comparing with Angular.

Things that should be focused are:

- ReactJS is only a library. It's not a framework like Angular. While this sounds that ReactJS is more flexible, in reality, it leads to confusion because you don't have standard of what to use. Example, if you want to use HTTP request. AngularJS has their own service ([$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)). With ReactJS, you choose yourself. One of them are [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
- If you want to create a ReactJS project from scratch, learn Webpack and ES6. Many tutorials use ES6 and Webpack. If you don't feel like you want to create the project from scratch, you can use boilerplates instead. But again, you might be confused to choose which boilerplate suits you since there are many boilerplates available from the community.

Anyway, things won't be as complicated as you think. As the time goes by, you'll be used to ReactJS. And I think, it's easier to learn. If you have a strong basic of Javascript, you won't meet a significant difficulty.

Comment: hey, thanks for answer. can plz share some good links for start learning.

Comment: You're welcome. You can check https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html to start learning about ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

I would learn react together with redux. React really wants a redux-
like pattern, and redux is simpler than alternative means of achieving that pattern.  So maybe learn a little redux first, and keep in mind that you want to achieve a very predictable segregation of program responsibilities.

1. Translate events into actions
2. Actions translate old state into new state with pure functions
3. ReactJS Components will simply reflect the state
4. You may bind events to react components, preferably injecting the event to action translation into the components

The rest should be very smooth sailing.

Comment: By the way, this is much simpler than angular

Comment: I think learning redux alongside react is fine, since you're most likely going to be using it in any non-trivial application. But be sure to understand why you're using it instead of setState and passing props yourself. Also consider the alternatives to redux like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) and [freactal](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/freactal). I personally really like freactal.